# html scraping using python topboxoffice list from imdb website

Tags: python, html

> URL: http://www.imdb.com/chart/?ref_=nv_ch_cht_2

I want you to print top box office list from above site (all the movies' rank, title, weekend, gross and weeks movies in the order)

**Example output:**
Rank:1
title: godzilla
weekend:$93.2M
Gross:$93.2M
Weeks: 1
Rank: 2
title: Neighbours

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple way to extract those entities by `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                          
import urllib2                                                         

url = "http://www.imdb.com/chart/?ref_=nv_ch_cht_2"                    

data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()                                     
page = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')                              

rows = page.findAll("tr", {'class': ['odd', 'even']}) 

for tr in rows:             
    for data in tr.findAll("td", {'class': ['titleColumn', 'weeksColumn','ratingColumn']}):
        print data.get_text()
```

P.S.-Arrange according to your will.

Comment: here i want print rank tilte gross weeks also how to get these??

Comment: I think `titleColumn` gives you the rank of the movies and `ratingColumn` will give the gross of the movies.

Comment: how can i do with lxml with out beatifulsoup any idea ??

Comment: I would rather suggest you using `Scrapy` or `pyQt` or `webscrapping` library to scrape things .

Comment: For `lxml` , I haven't done much , but this might help you - http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2008/12/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to scrape anything. See the answer  I gave here.

[How to scrape data from imdb business page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665509/how-to-scrape-data-from-imdb-business-page)

Answer (score 0):

The below Python script will give you, 
1) **List of Top Box Office movies** from IMDb 
2) And also the **List of Cast** for each of them.

```
from lxml.html import parse

def imdb_bo(no_of_movies=5):
    bo_url = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/'
    bo_page = parse(bo_url).getroot()
    bo_table = bo_page.cssselect('table.chart')
    bo_total = len(bo_table[0][2])

    if no_of_movies <= bo_total:
        count = no_of_movies
    else:
        count = bo_total

    movies = {}

    for i in range(0, count):
        mo = {}
        mo['url'] = 'http://www.imdb.com'+bo_page.cssselect('td.titleColumn')[i][0].get('href')
        mo['title'] = bo_page.cssselect('td.titleColumn')[i][0].text_content().strip()
        mo['year'] = bo_page.cssselect('td.titleColumn')[i][1].text_content().strip(" ()")
        mo['weekend'] = bo_page.cssselect('td.ratingColumn')[i*2].text_content().strip()
        mo['gross'] = bo_page.cssselect('td.ratingColumn')[(i*2)+1][0].text_content().strip()
        mo['weeks'] = bo_page.cssselect('td.weeksColumn')[i].text_content().strip()

        m_page = parse(mo['url']).getroot()
        m_casttable = m_page.cssselect('table.cast_list')

        flag = 0
        mo['cast'] = []
        for cast in m_casttable[0]:
            if flag == 0:
                flag = 1
            else:
                m_starname = cast[1][0][0].text_content().strip()
                mo['cast'].append(m_starname)

        movies[i] = mo

    return movies


if __name__ == '__main__':

    no_of_movies = raw_input("Enter no. of Box office movies to display:")
    bo_movies = imdb_bo(int(no_of_movies))

    for k,v in bo_movies.iteritems():
        print '#'+str(k+1)+'  '+v['title']+' ('+v['year']+')'
        print 'URL: '+v['url']
        print 'Weekend: '+v['weekend']
        print 'Gross: '+v['gross']
        print 'Weeks: '+v['weeks']
        print 'Cast: '+', '.join(v['cast'])
        print '\n'
```

**Output (run in terminal):**

```
parag@parag-innovate:~/python$ python imdb_bo_scraper.py 
Enter no. of Box office movies to display:3
#1  Cinderella (2015)
URL: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1661199?ref_=cht_bo_1
Weekend: $67.88M
Gross: $67.88M
Weeks: 1
Cast: Cate Blanchett, Lily James, Richard Madden, Helena Bonham Carter, Nonso Anozie, Stellan Skarsgård, Sophie McShera, Holliday Grainger, Derek Jacobi, Ben Chaplin, Hayley Atwell, Rob Brydon, Jana Perez, Alex Macqueen, Tom Edden


#2  Run All Night (2015)
URL: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2199571?ref_=cht_bo_2
Weekend: $11.01M
Gross: $11.01M
Weeks: 1
Cast: Liam Neeson, Ed Harris, Joel Kinnaman, Boyd Holbrook, Bruce McGill, Genesis Rodriguez, Vincent D'Onofrio, Lois Smith, Common, Beau Knapp, Patricia Kalember, Daniel Stewart Sherman, James Martinez, Radivoje Bukvic, Tony Naumovski


#3  Kingsman: The Secret Service (2014)
URL: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2802144?ref_=cht_bo_3
Weekend: $6.21M
Gross: $107.39M
Weeks: 5
Cast: Adrian Quinton, Colin Firth, Mark Strong, Jonno Davies, Jack Davenport, Alex Nikolov, Samantha Womack, Mark Hamill, Velibor Topic, Sofia Boutella, Samuel L. Jackson, Michael Caine, Taron Egerton, Geoff Bell, Jordan Long
```